# SML shorter base case syntax for my function

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

What would be a shorter syntax for this function? I'm noticing that a lot of programmers use pipes in their functions, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how I could do the same for this one.

```
fun test (i, x) = 
  if null x
then false
else
  if hd x = i then true
  else test(i, tl x)
//
val test = fn : ''a * ''a list -> bool
```

Comment: Even without pattern matching you can shorten that to `fun test (i,x) = not (null x) andalso (hd x = i orelse test (i, tl x))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shorter version:

```
fun test (_, []) = false
  | test (i, x::xs) = (x = i) orelse test (i, xs)
```

Here are the things I did:

1. Use pattern matching. In your second solution you're already pattern matching against the empty list, so this takes it a step further and pattern matches on the non-empty list (`x::xs`), making the use of `hd` and `tl` unnecessary.
2. Use the `_` pattern when you don't need the value.
3. Instead of `if P then true else Q`, write `P orelse Q`.

The parenthesis around `x = i` isn't strictly necessary. It looks a little confusing with the two different `=`s next to one another (one comes from the function definition, and the other is a binary operator), but this is also perfectly valid and means the same:

```
fun test (_, []) = false
  | test (i, x::xs) = x = i orelse test (i, xs)
```

Or indented a bit more conveniently:

```
fun test (_, []) = false
  | test (i, x::xs) =
      x = i orelse test (i, xs)
```

Comment: Awesome, this is really instructive. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found a pretty good solution. The pipes are used to define constructors, the first is the empty case, when `x` is an empty list, and the second is for the all others.

```
fun test (i, []) = false
  | test (i,x)  = if hd x = i then true else test(i, tl x)
```